# multiple number select statement sql

Tags: php, mysql

looking for something like

```
Select * FROM 'database' WHERE id = 1-40
```

something where I can select a number through a number like 1 through 40

multiple number select statement sql

Comment: You can use `BETWEEN`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Btw, you have a syntax error. Use backticks `\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM database_table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 40
```

This is an example page you can use: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_between

Comment: There is a syntax error. `'database'` <= right there ;) Yes, OP made that mistake. You should pick up on that.

Comment: Ok, next time i will test on my PhpMyAdmin before post, i'm sorry, now should work

Comment: This page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html will help you. It has a lot of information regarding table/column identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The [`between`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select * FROM `tablename` WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways for selecting range in DB:

```
Select * FROM `database.tablename` WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 40 ;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `DATABASE.TABLENAME` WHERE ID >= 1 AND <=40;
```

In case, you want to select multiple items which are not in range, you can use:

```
Select * FROM `database.tablename` WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5,6.....40);
```